# Upgraded flipflop square wave generator - did I do good?

Tags: transistors, function-generator, multivibrator

[image: schematic]

I've drawn up a simple multi-frequency square wave generator, based on a astable multivibrator circut, with frequency trimmed by the two ganged pots (both 100k) and the range set by a DPDT switch, which switches capacitors (1uF, 10nF, 100p hard connected). There is an aditional output stage that "squaryfies" the signal and increases possible output current. Should I take the output, to steer a BJT for example, from the emmiter? Can I make the signal AC (-2.5V low to +2.5V high) by adding a capacitor?
Btw, collector R's are 1k and output base is 2k2

Comment: Regardless of the quality of the circuit itself (which I don't have the time to analyze right now), I just want to say that is _fantastically_ well drawn. They don't teach us how to draw circuits like that anymore.

Comment: @Hearth Well haha, thats what happens when youre bored at school with A4 paper, a ruler and a pencil. The funiest part is that i have dysgraphia and my handwriting is so bad. I have never tried to hand draw schematics in "high quality mode" before.

Comment: My best advice to you is grab a free simulation tool, do some hardwork understanding how to use it (learning curve) and get yourself above where you are now to test out your ideas.

Comment: @Andyaka I simulated it in ltspice, it does seem to work.

Comment: You might consider leaving that as an answer to your own question but make sure you simulated it correctly (no ambiguities like output load not being present).

Comment: Simulations are simulations, they dont always show the real life performance, I also wanted for someone more expirienced to look at it. Ill put up an anserw when im finished with the pcb and see it working.